# UITextView Text Not Displaying

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a text view in a custom table view cell that I'm trying to add text to. The strings I'm using have the correct info but it's not showing up in the text view.

In cellForRowAt indexPath:

```
cell.infoField.text = "\(distanceInfo)\n\n\(addressInfo)"
print("\(distanceInfo)\n\n\(addressInfo)")
```

The print statement prints this:

```
0.6912655785507482 Miles

600 S Preston St, Louisville, KY 40202
```

Here is the custom cell.

[image]

Here is what is shown. The text view is empty.[image]

Comment: Did you connect outlets?

Comment: @mag_zbc Yes I did.

Comment: Did you add constrains

Comment: @E.Coms I'm using auto layout and have the row height adjusting dynamically using UITableView.automaticDimension.

Comment: Did you add height constrain for the textview? It may solve this invisible problem.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Great to hear it